# Split returns non-matches

Tags: python, regex

When using split with one capturing group in the pattern with an alternative, Python returns unexpected, unmatched values.

For example, the code below is supposed to return either "a" or a number. It does exactly that when you use it with findall however split returns non matches and empty strings.

```
x = re.compile(r'(a|-?[0-9]+)')

# returns ['45', '444', '19', 'a']
print(x.findall("45, 444 < 19, abc"))

# returns ['', '45', ', ', '444', ' < ', '19', ', ', 'a', 'bc']
print(x.split("45, 444 < 19, abc"))
```

The expected results are what findall does. I don't understand why split behaves differently.

Edit: Also when you don't use a capturing group, findall still works but split gets worse by not returning the matched results too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can slightly change your regex expression in `re.split`:

```
import re
print(list(filter(None, re.split('[^\da]+', "45, 444 < 19, abc"))))
```

Output:

```
['45', '444', '19', 'a']
```

Comment: I've modified the pattern a bit to accept values like 1.e-10 and minus sign and it works.

Answer (score 5):

The docs of [re.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) state that if you use a capturing group then those are also returned. So you split on your expression AND return the capturing groups.

Your pattern `(a|-?[0-9]+)` captures in a group:

```
45
444
19
a
```

What is unmatched is (and so returned)

```
, 
 < 
 ,
```

Resulting in:

```
['', '45', ', ', '444', ' < ', '19', ', ', 'a', 'bc']
```

The first entry is empty due to the split on `[0-9]+` because it splits that from the start of the string.

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be a misunderstanding [what `split` is *supposed* to do](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split), and how it differs from [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall). Basically, without a capturing group, `split` should return exactly those parts that `findall` does *not* return. After all, it will `split` the string by those matched, just like `str.split` does, but with a regex pattern.

```
>>> re.findall(r'(a|-?[0-9]+)', "45, 444 < 19, abc")
['45', '444', '19', 'a']

>>> re.split(r'a|-?[0-9]+', "45, 444 < 19, abc")
['', ', ', ' < ', ', ', 'bc']
```

And *with* a capturing group, as in your case, both the matches (as with `findall`) and the stuff in between (as with `split`) is returned.

```
>>> sorted(_ + __) == sorted(re.split(r'(a|-?[0-9]+)', "45, 444 < 19, abc"))
True
```

`split` and `findall` *can* be used interchangeably, e.g. if you want to find everything that matches some pattern, but that pattern is very complicated, it might be easier to find a regular expression for the *complement* of that pattern and use `split` instead, or vice versa. But in general, if you want to *find* stuff, you should use `findall`.

Comment: "it will split the string by those matched, just like str.split does"

Didn't think like that. It makes more sense now. I was expecting it to be work like findall because I'm just starting to regex and I'm looking at the docs. In the example on the docs, I thought "\W+" would match words instead of anything else thus example on the documentation made me think it returns matched results...

Comment: @ErenKara Ah, that explains your misunderstanding. `\w` is word- and `\W` is non-word characters, and analogeously with `\d` and `\D`, `\s` and `\S`, and so on.